# Role Count using Graph Api against a tenant

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Is there a way to find each `role` that exists against a `tenant` and `number of users` which have been assigned against each `role` using `GraphServiceClient` or `GraphConnection` class? I am using C#.

Comment: In your question you have mentioned GraphServiceClient but you had originally tagged only Azure AD Graph API and not Microsoft Graph API. Same way your comment on my other post.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52931467/how-do-i-get-the-assigned-role-of-a-user-in-azure-active-directory/52938504#comment96894829_52938504  mentions graph.windows.net, so I'm not sure which one you're looking for and hence I did both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Directory Roles** - Finding all directory roles and count of their members for tenant

I have given sample code for both Microsoft Graph API (https://graph.microsoft.com) as well as Azure AD Graph API (https://graph.windows.net), but it would be strongly recommended to use newer Microsoft Graph API unless there is something specific that you aren't able to get from it and only then look at Azure AD Graph API.

Look here for more detailed comparisons [Microsoft Graph or Azure AD Graph](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2016/07/08/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/)

Here are nuget package and class details, as you've asked in comments:

- `Microsoft.Graph` nuget package - to work with `Microsoft Graph API` and use `GraphServiceClient` class.
- `Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient` nuget package - to work with Azure AD Graph API and use `ActiveDirectoryClient` class.

*Microsoft Graph API*

API's - [List directoryRoles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryrole-list?view=graph-rest-1.0) and [List members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryrole-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0)

```
var roles = await graphServiceClient.DirectoryRoles.Request().GetAsync();

var members = graphServiceClient.DirectoryRoles[role.Id].Members.Request().GetAsync();
```

*Azure AD Graph API*

API's - [Get Directory Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/directoryroles-operations#get-directory-roles--) and [Get a directory role's members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/directoryroles-operations#get-a-directory-roles-members--)

```
var directoryRoles =  activeDirectoryClient.DirectoryRoles.ExecuteAsync();

var members = await activeDirectoryClient.DirectoryRoles[role.ObjectId].Members.ExecuteAsync();
```

NOTE: While testing code I also noticed a slight difference in behavior of the 2 API's. Microsoft Graph only returns Users when you ask for members of a directory role. Azure AD Graph on the other hand returned both users and service principals. See my code for a special check in case of Azure AD Graph.

Also note that many of the results you get will be paginated collections, so you may need to handle pagination in case of multiple pages of results.

---

**Application Roles** - Finding all Application Roles for an application and then finding Number of users through App Role Assignments.

[Application Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/app-roles) are specific to an application registered in Azure AD. Role Assignments collection for that application can be read by going through the service principal for that application in the tenant.

*Azure AD Graph API*

App Roles

```
var app = activeDirectoryClient.Applications["<applicationObjectId>"].ExecuteAsync().Result;
var appRoles = app.AppRoles;
```

App Role Assignments

```
ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(new Uri("https://graph.windows.net/<tenantGuid>"),
async () => await GetTokenForApplication());

var servicePrincipal = activeDirectoryClient.ServicePrincipals.Where(x => x.AppId == "<applicationId>").ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage[0];
var appRoleAssignments = activeDirectoryClient.ServicePrincipals[servicePrincipal.ObjectId].AppRoleAssignedTo.ExecuteAsync().Result;
int userCountForApp = 0;
foreach(var appRoleAssignment in appRoleAssignments.CurrentPage)
{
    if (appRoleAssignment.PrincipalType == "User")
    {
        userCountForApp++;
        Console.WriteLine("Role Id = {0} and User Name = {1}", appRoleAssignment.Id, appRoleAssignment.PrincipalDisplayName);
    }
}
```

*Microsoft Graph API*

The ability to read all application specific roles assigned to a user (i.e. AppRoleAssignments) is only available as part of Microsoft Graph API beta endpoint. So it's not stable enough to be used in production code and you won't find Client SDK support for C#. Read more specific points in [this SO Post by Marc LaFleur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47161815/how-to-call-microsoft-graph-beta-api-from-c-sharp/47167606#47167606)

Here are the relevant API's though:

- [AppRoleAssignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/approleassignment-get?view=graph-rest-beta)
- [AppRoles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/approle?view=graph-rest-beta)

Comment: What package I need to install to get ActiveDirectoryClient? The class which I have is GraphConnection and that doesn't seem to have Applications property.

Comment: Also, when I try to call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/roleDefinitions using graph explorer, I am getting Request not appliccable to target tenant.

Comment: @FIrePanda `Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient` nuget package to work with Azure AD Graph API and use `ActiveDirectoryClient` class. `Microsoft.Graph` package to work with `Microsoft Graph API` and use `GraphServiceClient` class. Also, can you please clarify which roles you're interested in? Directory roles assigned to users or some registered Application specific roles assigned to users?

Comment: So, what is the difference between directory roles and app roles?

Comment: @FIrePanda As the name suggests.. **Directory role** is the role that is assigned to a user for entire directory (i.e. this particular tenant in Azure AD).. more info - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles ..from portal you can see this by going directly to any user and then directory role navigation node.. there are built-in roles available like Application Administrator, Global Administrator, User Administrator and so on..

Comment: @FIrePanda **Application Role** is specific to only an application registered with Azure AD. You first define your roles in App Manifest and then assign them to individual users or groups.. more info here.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/app-roles ..these roles are just available as information for e.g. as claims in token.. enforcing what that role can or cannot do is responsibility of application itself.

Comment: Are you sure, graph sdk provides directory roles in paged format? I tried to fetch multiple directory roles but they all got returned as part of first page. I think sdk is just a wrapper over graph Api.

Also, this link too says that directory roles are not paged. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging

Comment: I think my comment about Pagination is for AppRoleAssignments collection as that's what I was working on first while answering, but later realized you're probably looking for directory roles.. take a look at the code where I use `foreach(var appRoleAssignment in appRoleAssignments.CurrentPage)` Docs link you have for paging about directory roles seems valid.. also AFAIK number of directory role templates is pretty small, so no paging would make sense.

Comment: Also, the directory role which we get, would it be culture based or role display name would always be in english?