# microsoft graph - permissions info on file in one drive - how to get additional info

Tags: java, file-permissions, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks

i would like to know if the link shared is password protected and its expiration date if exists
i make an API call
 `graphClient.users('email').drive().items(id).permissions()`

but don't seem to receive that information and cannot locate another call that will return it

if there is another way to call the api not via sdk that is acceptable as well
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `beta` endpoint - you can point to it using the SDK by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47161815/how-to-call-microsoft-graph-beta-api-from-c-sharp) (the answer is for C# but it should apply to Java as well). The SDK may not have the properties on it, but they should be available in the `AdditionalData` property.